# LINQ Query-Select records where all the children meet a condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a One to Many relationship. I want to select all records from the parent table where it's children all meet a specific condition. If one of the children fails then that record is not returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
var results = parentCollection.Where(p => p.Children.All(c => <condition>));
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Unless you mean using Linq to SQL, as I fear you might. In which case this may not work.

Comment: One of the best answer . Love you